# reCaptcha.v2 'undefined index g-recaptcha-response'

Tags: php, recaptcha

As in title. I believe my code should work without any `notices` according to Google's API but apparently it's not. I'm at the moment testing reCaptcha on `localhost` via `XAMPP`.

```
$key = "your key";
$check = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret='.$key.'&response='.$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
$response = json_decode($key);
if($response->success===false){
    $_SESSION['err_bot']="Error";
}
```

Additionaly i'm receiving `Notice` in this lane:

"trying to get property of non-object in" `if($response->success===false){`

I've searched some similar problems and few people had these notices because they had `form` in `table`. I'm using `fullPage.js` which is pretty much about tables. Could this be a problem?

**Solved**

```
if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
    echo verify($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
}

function verify($response){
  $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  $key = "your key";
  $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
  $full_url = $url.'?secret='.$key.'&response='.$response.'&remoteip='.$ip;

  $data = json_decode(file_get_contents($full_url));
  if(isset($data->success) && $data->success == true){
     return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Your code containts two errors, and one error in syntax. You should turn on error reporting, you'll find out that check = file_get_contents, won't work. (It does only, because php is trying to fix it), and the variable $key is obviously not a piece of json code.

Comment: Hmm, will check that, thanks for pointing that out.